# Template or component engine, that compiles to static files

Tags: javascript, templates, webpack

I'm looking for template-based or component-based engine, That I can use to build a set of static HTML files. For example, I have a site with few pages  main page, contacts and about. All pages has a different body content, but same headers, footers etc., I can easily solve this problem with SSR or SPA frameworks, but I think this is too much for this site and I need a simple solution.

What I want is a basic ablilty to reuse some components and capability of webpack, hot reload and other modern stuff.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem? I'm migrating old from Yeman+Guntr+Assemble to something modern, but I can't find helpful documentation teaching how to do this with WebPack.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://www.ivarprudnikov.com/static-website-multiple-html-pages-using-webpack-plus-github-example/

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i found solution that fits me: parcel + posthtml-expressions, this is lightweid and pretty simple, but thats what exactly i searched for